# Contextual REST. How?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

What are the ways to implement contextual REST, ex. GET */ws/shoppingcart* returns the corresponding user's (here is context) shopping cart. This is just one of the example.
Do I need to setup SSL and use https:// instead of http:// for serving each user request?

**Edited**

The whole story: I need to develop back-end REST services, which then will be used by mobile devices (native applications). The language for back-end is Java. So, there are lots of users, so I need to be sure to know the current "logged-in" user, so can associate any request with the right user identity (authentication). So, I would like to know what is the right way to implement it? Starting from the begging to end:

- send username/password for the initial request
- associate each of the following request with the current user
- reject service request, if no current user, so anonymous call, i.e. only public requests are allowed for anonymous users
- the solution should be secure enough

Comment: Please provide more examples of what you mean. One example is not enough.

Comment: what software are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

The way we have implemented something similar is by require that all requests have a "ticket" send in the header. The ticket is created and returned by the initial /login method.

We store the ticket in a database and use sliding expiration.

Comment: So, the initial login request was SSL/TLS request? And if anyone potentially get access to the "ticket" he/she can temporarily get unauthorized access to the resource until the ticket is expired, right?

Answer (score 0):

We use SSL and retrieve the user's identity from the certificate. However, you could use a standard or custom header field. One example would be passing this in a cookie via the `cookie` header field. Another possibility is to include this user context in your URI scheme, though this would be much harder if you are not using hypermedia (HATEOAS) in your "protocol" (e.g. clients accessing the service through a well known entry point then navigating solely based on links provided in the responses)

Obviously, any of these influence your "protocol" and need to be documented appropriately so clients know what to do.